# How to use timeout with $.ajax method of jQuery

Tags: jquery, timeout

Hi my question is that I am using jQuery ajax method $.ajax() to hit a web service in my application. If I hit a web service by using my method. Then if I have not  got any response from service. Then how can I handle this problem. How can I use timeout in my function for delay service response.

Comment: It's not very clear what the problem is. Please post your code and explain what it should do and what it does instead. (It is very likely  that a timeout is not the correct solution to whatever the problem is.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timeout setting. The call will then throw an error, which you can detect is a timeout using the `textstatus` argument.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/some/url",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(response) { alert(response); },
    error: function(jqXHR, textstatus, errorThrown ) {
        if(textstatus==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
        } else { 
            alert(textstatus);
        }
    }
});​
```